# AJAX URL request doesn't work from desktop

Tags: jquery, ajax

Running this simple AJAX with WAMP localhost I can pull JSON from a web address.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $.ajax({
      url: 'http://time.jsontest.com/',
      dataType: 'jsonp', 
      success: function(json) 
      {
          console.log(json);
      }
  });
});
```

However I cannot connect if I try running normally through a browser, why is that?

Google CDN:

```
<src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js">
```

Comment: Look in the JavaScript console. There will almost certainly be an error telling you what's going wrong.

Comment: Did you disable browser security while working locally ?

Comment: I found it's the CDN not working. The exact same CDN loads through WAMP but not through standard browser: <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>. It's the exact same file, one opening localhost/file the other doubleclick yet one works one doesn't

Comment: As far as I've known, leaving out http: from the URL is a trick for using both HTTP and HTTPS. But adding http: to the URL makes it work, and your answer makes sense. You can make it an answer, I'll edit the actual question to include CDN address. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "standard browser" you mean you're viewing the page through a `file://` URL, then yes, that `src` for the `script` tag is not going to work.

A URL starting with `//` is a [protocol-relative URL](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/skipping-protocol.html). Just like `/foo` is relative to the current protocol, server, and port, `//` is relative to just the protocol. So it inherits the protocol of the containing document.

This is usually used so that you use `http` or `https` for the script depending on the container document. But if you do that and you're using a local file (the `file` protocol), then your relative URL ends up resolving to:

```
file://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js
```

...which won't work (well, unless you have a directory at the root of your file system called ajax.googleapis.com with the subdirectory ajax containing libs containing jquery containing 1.10.1 that has the file in it).

Just put `http:` or `https:` before the `//` in the URL to make it absolute.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think is that you're using a local copy of jQuery and it doesn't exist on the server relative to where you've uploaded it? Do you have any errors?

Answer (score -2):

your local server acts as a compiler. just running it on your browser without a server means no compiler. NO COMPILER NO SUCCESSFUL EXECUTION

just a theory subject to debate. i hope you find it helpful

Comment: Javascript is implicitly compiled by browsers, it doesn't need a server.

Comment: Sami - There's that handy "delete" link under the answer... I've used it more than once. :-)